# c: Generating random numbers using a PCG implementation

Tags: c, random

I am trying to implement the PCG random number generator in c. It's kind of difficult for me to wrap my head around the examples since I am a beginner in c. So far I tried to implement the minimal version which can be found [here](https://github.com/imneme/pcg-c-basic).

Here is my code which produces now some (hopefully) pseudo random numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "pcg_basic.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    pcg32_random_t rngptr;
    pcg32_srandom_r(&rngptr, time(NULL), (intptr_t)&rngptr);

    for (int round = 1; round <= 10; ++round) {
        printf(" %f\n", ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&rngptr) ,-32));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is that even a good implementation or can this be improved better?

The problem: I want to use random numbers everywhere in my code and not only in the `main()` function. How can I do this? I tried:

```
double myrand(){
        pcg32_random_t rngptr;
        pcg32_srandom_r(&rngptr, time(NULL), (intptr_t)&rngptr);
        return ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&rngptr) ,-32);
}
```

However, this approach does not work and seems wrong to me. But I don't know how to do it better.

Can someone please show me a simple approach to get good pseudo random numbers in c which work in every part of the code?

Comment: you need an initialization flag, else you'll get the same number over and over.

Comment: I don't see any *implementation* of PCG, you're just **using** one.

Comment: "*Can someone please show me a simple approach to get good pseudo random numbers in c*" <- here you have to define "good". `rand()` in most standard C implementations is "good enough" for at least games.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How do I do that?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you. I updated the title. I need good and fast random numbers for a Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: @Samuel Many `rand()` implementations are "ok" for that as well, but indeed, you can't be sure, as the C standard doesn't give any requirement for the quality of `rand()`.

Comment: @Samuel Felix answer looks like something I could have answered (only: it's more polished). I suggest that you accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the implementation you use, looking at these lines:

```
double myrand(){
        pcg32_random_t rngptr;
        pcg32_srandom_r(&rngptr, time(NULL), (intptr_t)&rngptr);
        return ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&rngptr) ,-32);
}
```

The second line **seeds** the random number generator. Doing this on every call makes the actual PRNG ineffectual.

Every PRNG works by holding some internal state and calculating the next state from the previous one using some more-or-less complicated arithmetic operations. Part of the internal state is then returned as the next "random" number.

As the internal state has to start *somewhere*, you have to *seed* every PRNG *exactly once* (and use something like `time()` for it, to start somewhere different at every run).

A simple version of this code could therefore look like:

```
double myrand(){
    static int initialized = 0;
    static pcg32_random_t rngptr;
    if (!initialized)
    {
        pcg32_srandom_r(&rngptr, time(NULL), (intptr_t)&rngptr);
        initialized = 1;
    }
    return ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&rngptr) ,-32);
}
```

This is no longer thread-safe as there's only one instance of the PRNG (represented by the `pcg32_random_t` variable) in the whole program.

Another way would be to make your function actually take a pointer to your PRNG and manage creation and seeding somewhere outside (e.g. once in `main()`):

```
double myrand(pcg32_random_t *rngptr){
    return ldexp(pcg32_random_r(rngptr) ,-32);
}


int main(void)
{
    // do this once:
    pcg32_random_t rngptr;
    pcg32_srandom_r(&rngptr, time(NULL), (intptr_t)&rngptr);

    // [...]

    double x = myrand(&rngptr);
}
```

---

The basically same thing applies to the C standard functions `srand()` and `rand()`: You must call `srand()` exactly once for seeding the PRNG. With these functions, the internal state is `static` (in the C standard library), so you don't have to pass anything and using these functions isn't thread-safe.

Here's a *very simple and stupid* example implementation of the standard C `rand()` for a `RAND_MAX` of `0x7fffffff`, which could maybe help to understand the general concept of a PRNG better:

```
static unsigned long long int randval = 1;

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    randval = seed;
}

int rand(void)
{
    randval *= 1103515245;
    randval += 12345;
    return (int)((randval / 65536) & 0x7fffffff);
}
```

As you can see, `randval` is kept secret, but calling `srand()` sets it, so affects the outcome of the next call to `rand()`.

Comment: Your first solution looks easy to implement but the seconds one looks faster. Is there really no way to get a random number without passing a pointer?